# Inserting many converted leads through Apex data loader(Salesforce)

Tags: salesforce

If I have some leads in my Salesforce org which are already converted to some Accounts or Opportunity and now I have to insert the same converted leads to my other Salesforce Org then how it can be done for bulk records.
I have the required permission for converting the LEADS i.e. Edit and Create on Accounts, Opportunity, Contacts along with 'convert leads' permission.

I am seeking for the steps to be followed to accomplish this with full details.

Thanks
Chirag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this sorted out.
In order to insert Converted Leads into SALESFORCE, we have to raise a case in SF in order to enable these fields: CONVERTEDACCOUNTID, CONVERTEDCONTACTID, CONVERTEDOPPORTUNITYID and CONVERTEDDATE in editable mode.
These are the audit fields, once enabled then you can load/insert converted leads into your environment.

Following Points to Consider:

1. Firstly, Load Account, Contact and Opportunity which needs to be associated with the converted lead.
2. Next prepare a csv files with information of lead and get the ids from previous step and   load it into the appropriate converted fields of file as mentioned above.
3. The field Isconverted should be set to true.
4. The CONVERTEDDATE must be created after the Lead's CreatedDate, Otherwise it will give error. [this is a common sence ;)]

Also these Audit Fields are automatically disabled in two weeks, so try to finish your work within this time.

Thanks & Regards

Chirag

Answer (score 0):

Export data from salesforce Org1. OR use 'salesforce to salesforce' sharing feature to send data from one org to another org.

Write a apex job to mass convert leads to accounts.

Comment: Ganesh, Can you send a sample code for 'Apex Job', to mass convert leads to accounts. iF you have it.

Comment: in my Salesforce Production we are not using this 'Salesforce to Salesforce' functionality, so can you suggest some other idea or technique to solve this issue.